# How to get json response and use it

Tags: json

I am trying to submit the form and get JSON response from a URL and fetch "payment_url" so I can use it. It's a payment gateway API. I am new to JSON so that's why don't know how to do that I already search on google and StackOverflow but not able to understand method. Please help me to understand it.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="URL">
     <input type="text" name="abc" />
     <input type="text" name="def" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JSON Response on URL:

```
{"result":"The Pay Page is created.","response_code":"code","payment_url":"URL","p_id":ID}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what language do you want to parse your json ? how do you send json ? is your form `application/json` ?

Comment: the website is in PHP language. so it's better if I can phrase it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not support JSON as a media type for form submissions !

You should submit your from with `XMLHttpRequest` first:

```
var formData = new FormData(yourForm);
$.ajax({ // this is jquery XHR - AJAX
  type: "POST",
  url: "serverUrl",
  data: formData,
  success: function(){},
  dataType: "json",
  contentType : "application/json"
});
```

Then in the server-side use `json_decode()`

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); // the second param defines if the response should be an array or an object.
```

Note when you send `application/json` in PHP you can not access it using `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: getting error


(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'WEBSITE URL' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you doing a CORS ? then you must set that header in the destination. Search about cors !

Comment: so far I've done this, it is accessing the link but don't know how to pass data

function getJSONP(url, success) {
    var ud = '_' + +new Date,
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
              || document.documentElement;
    window[ud] = function(data) {
        head.removeChild(script);
        success && success(data);
    };
    script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
    head.appendChild(script);
    }
    getJSONP('URL', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

Comment: @QararUlHassan I didn't quite get what you post ! could you possibly update your question with more details and the code you provided here in the comments ? But for now, the data is the object you get isn't it ?